# Automating picture loading into Delphi TImage Picture (TJPEGImage)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I need to automatically load pictures into TImage. I can figure out the location of the jpeg by the pas file name. If the file name is "chapter14screen45" then I know it is folder 14 then the images folder inside the chapter, then 014.jpeg should be loaded into Image1 object.

Comment: What exactly is the question then?

Comment: You need to clarify. Do you have some code to show?

Comment: The question is how do I load the image object automatically if I know the image location? And if the image location can be dynamic in that it is based off of the PAS file name

Comment: I think you need to tell us what "automatic" means

Answer (score 2):

Example on how to load a Jpeg image into a TImage component :

```
procedure LoadJpgImage(DestImage : TImage ; Name : String);
begin
DestImage.Picture.LoadFromFile(Name);
end;
```

Where Name is the absolute path to the image for example : `'D:\jpeg\014.jpeg'`.

If you are using an old Delphi version that does not include native TImage support for Jpeg then you need to find a third party implementation to be able to load a Jpeg Image into a TImage component.

Comment: Delphi 6 understood jpeg files

Comment: Ah true, was it png support that they added in 2009 then? Can't remember.

Comment: I thought it was 2007 for png, but around then anyway

Comment: Got my wheels turning.. I'll build on this.. thanks